# I need to show Tree view instead of Form view after i inherit CRM Module to my Custom Module in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I had successfully inherited the CRM module into my custom module.I'm able to view the Form view but i need to show Tree view first.When i click Lead button in the main menu i'm able to show the form view (like in img1), but i need to show the tree view(like in img 2)

img 1 [image: Img 1]

img 2 [image: Img2]

lead_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

  <record id="view_lead_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">bala.lead</field>
        <field name="model">bala.lead</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Leads">
                <field name="contact_name"/>
                <field name="lead_source"/>
                <field name="lead_status"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
</record>


 <!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
<record id="crm_case_form_view_leads_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">CRM - Leads Form</field>
<field name="model">bala.lead</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" />
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="email_from" postion="replace"/>
    <field name="contact_name" position="replace"/>
    <label for="contact_name" position="replace">
      <br/>
    </label>
    <xpath expr="//label[@for='street']" position="before">
                <field name="contact_name"/>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//label[@for='section_id']" position="before">
                <field name="lead_source"/>
                <field name="lead_status"/>
    </xpath>

    <field name="function" position="replace"/>
    <field name="partner_name" position="replace"/>
    <field name="priority" position="replace"/>
    <field name="categ_ids" position="replace"/>
    <field name="partner_id" position="replace"/>

</field>
</record>
<!-- ===========================Action layout=========================== -->
<record id="new_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Leads</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">bala.lead</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_lead_tree"/>
</record>
<!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
<menuitem name ="Lead" id = "menu_lis_lab" />
  <menuitem name="Leads" id="sub_lead" parent="menu_lis_lab" />
    <menuitem name="Create Lead" id="create_lead" parent="sub_lead" action="new_lead"/> 
</data>
</openerp>
```

then on click of any lead i'm getting img 3 (invalid view)and on click on Create button img 4 is being displyed , but i need to get img1

img 3 
[image: img3]
 img 4 [image: img4]

Answer (score 2):

Add tree view to your xml file, and you can add more fields in this according to requirement,

```
<record id="view_lead_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">bala.lead</field>
        <field name="model">bala.lead</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Leads">
                <field name="contact_name"/>
                <field name="lead_source"/>
                <field name="lead_status"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
</record>
```

update your act_window

```
<record id="new_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Lead</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">bala.lead</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_lead_tree"/>
</record>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm getting list view but on click of it i'm getting different details and if i click on create form i'm getting different form unlike img1 .I took screen shots how can i share with you??

Comment: @ Mansi i have updated my question please see the images